# pass variables from front to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, quasar

i have a vue js project with front end and i have a field with variables that i want it when its changed it will go to backend and change there too any idea? the variable is id tage like in this code

```
app.get('/payments', (request, response) => {
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
  let payments = []


db.collection("payments").where("id", "==", idtag).get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
    payments.push(doc.data())
  })
  response.send(payments)
  console.log('payments:',payments)
})
})
```

and this is the front end

```
export default defineComponent({

  setup () {
    const loadinga = ref(false)
    const idtag=ref(null)
    const filter = ref('')
return {
      events: [ '2019/02/01', '2019/02/05', '2019/02/06' ],
      date : ref('2019-02-22 21:02'),
      columns,
      loadinga,
      idtag,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the ID part of the request url:

```js
// backend assuming this is express
app.get('/payments/:id', (request, response) => {
    // use the id in some way
    const idtag = req.params.id;
    ...
});
```

In your frontend code, you need to [watch](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) the idTag and initiate a new request each time it changes.

```js
// frontend
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const idtag = ref(null);

    watch(idtag, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      fetch(`/payments/${newValue}`)
        .then(raw => raw.json())
        .then(data => {
          // do something with the data
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(console.warn);
    });

    return { idtag };
  }
})
```

If you need this to run immediately, you should use [watchEffect](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect) instead. But since your value is null at the beginning, I don't think this is the case.

Comment: thank u for the explaining but this doesn't work for me because im using axios like this code      getPayments() {
    
         this.$axios.get(`${ process.env.API}/payments`).then(response => {
         this.payments = response.data
    
       }).catch(err => {    this.$q.dialog({
            title: 'Could not load Posts',
            message: 'Please check your connection to the internet '
    
        })
    
    
          })
    
     },

Comment: @omarjasim, you cannot use process.env in frontend code. The code runs in the users browser.

Comment: ok i tried to mix it with my code but im getting this warning

Comment: runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?f781:38 [Vue warn]: Invalid watch source:  3306f3a8-9fe8-4e55-8791-cd3897fd91d7 A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types.

Comment: @omarjasim, perhaps because its null, I am not sure. Maybe try making ot 0 or "" once. I would think it counts as ref since its `const idtag = ref(null)`. Ref is one of the listed sources of your error.

Comment: thank you the code worked now but i removed watch argument but im having a problem now that i have to run the function two times to get the results(first time the array will be empty from server second time im getting the array) is that because of removing the watch function?

Comment: @omarjasim, I cannot tell you because I dont know how your code looks. In a nutshell my answer is correct. This is how you react to state changes. Its also documented as such, as you can see from the 2 posted links.